# Paginating a List in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

Probably a silly question but can't seem to figure it out on my own. Let's say I have a long list of items displayed on the page. I simply want to paginate it into pages of e.g. 5 items per page. To avoid reinventing the wheel, looked up a couple of libraries and [react-js-pagination](https://github.com/vayser/react-js-pagination) seems to do what I need. But for the life of me I can't figure it out.
What I have tried per the simplified example below:

- Put `<Pagination />` and my list in the same div.
- Gave my list items a class of `page-item` per the API docs.

No luck. I added a parent of `<ul>` and/or put my items in `<li>` tags. Even gave the parent `<ul>` a class of "pagination". Nothing. The only difference I am able to achieve is all items appearing in the same line like you see in the screenshot. Anything you figure out I am missing is appreciated.

```
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activePage: 1
        }
    }

    handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
        this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="pagination">
                    <li className="page-item">1</li>
                    <li className="page-item">2</li>
                    <li className="page-item">3</li>
                    <li className="page-item">4</li>
                    <li className="page-item">5</li>
                    <li className="page-item">6</li>
                    <li className="page-item">7</li>
                    <li className="page-item">8</li>
                    <li className="page-item">9</li>
                    <li className="page-item">10</li>
                    <li className="page-item">11</li>
                </ul>
                <Pagination
                    activePage={this.state.activePage}
                    itemsCountPerPage={2}
                    totalItemsCount={11}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                    onChange={this.handlePageChange.bind(this)}
                    itemClass="page-item"
                    linkClass="page-link"
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Result so far:

[image]

Comment: Its only the pagination component, you don't filter nothing in this example

Comment: "react-js-pagination seems to do what I need" have you read their docs? It explicitly states the component is "dumb". "A ReactJS dumb component to render a pagination." It **only** renders pager. So it is up to you to implement actual pagination logic.

Comment: Yep. I did read the the docs but not thoroughly enough I guess. :) Cheers for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the **pagination logic**.  Its not so trivial, here is a simple example (not related to `react-js-pagination`):

```
function Pagination({ pageSize, children }) {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);

  const totalChildren = React.Children.count(children);
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalChildren / pageSize);

  const childrenArray = _.chunk(React.Children.toArray(children), pageSize);

  return (
    <>
      {childrenArray[currentPage]}
      <Radio.Group defaultValue={0} size={totalPages}>
        {generateNButtons(totalPages, setCurrentPage)}
      </Radio.Group>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-pagination]

Comment: You are right. I thought it was so trivial. So, I guess there is no such paginator where you just pass it a list of components and it displays them in pages. Cheers for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The paginator and the displayed content are two differents things and are managed separatly. Your pagination is ok, but on each `onChange` event, you need to get x elements from your array of data or API or whatever, x being your `pageSize` (I guess it's `itemsCountPerPage` here). The retrieved elements are x elements, starting at the index `x * pageIndex`, `pageIndex` being the current page (1, 2 3, etc., named `pageRangeDisplayed` here is think).

So you need to do the maths around your apginator, it does not include it.

Comment: Cheers Quentin. Oversimplified things in my head. Doing what you suggested now.

Comment: Note that it's usually the back-end which take care of returning paginated results since you don't want to load all your data in your app. Also doing this allow you to add filters on the same Api. Be aware that my calcul aren't accurate because you need to care about filters that return no results

Comment: Cheers. Noted. Will do.